# how to acess variable in the flask main function

Tags: python, python-3.x, gunicorn

how can I access object declared in flask main in my views.py

```
           from flask_restful import Resource, request
            from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, get_jwt_identity, create_access_token
            from datetime import timedelta
            import string
            import views
            import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
            #import client
            from run import api,app
    def startup():
        client = mqtt.Client(client_id=" ", clean_session=True, userdata=None,transport="tcp")
        global client
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.on_message = on_message
        #client.message_callback_add("SQT/CAP/REG/MODELNO/SLNO",send_command)
        #client.message_callback_add("SQT/CAP/+/+/DAT",data_receive)
        client.username_pw_set('dave','sectorqube')

        #client.tls_set(ca_certs="ssl2-master/server.crt", certfile="ssl2-master/ca.crt", keyfile="ssl2-master/ca-nopass.key", cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)
        #client.tls_insecure_set(True)
        client.connect("ec2-13-127-241-50.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com",1883)
        client.loop_start()   
if __name__ == "__main__":
            views.startup()
            app.run(threaded=True)
```

when I try to access the global variable from my views.py it says name error

```
from flask_restful import Resource, request
from datetime import timedelta
import string
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from flask_restful import reqparse
import json
import ssl
def comand_off():
    topic="DEVICE/COMMAND"
    print(client.publish(topic,"OFF"))
    return {"success":True}
```

the error I am getting is this

> print(client.publish(topic,"ON")) NameError: name 'client' is not
>   defined

i run using gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 resources:app

Comment: `global` needs to be declared before you create the name. However, globals are likely to cause a lot of pain in a webapp. Also, please fix your indentation, it's very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

if your main script is called main.py, you can do

```
import main
```

Then reference it in views.py with

```
main.client
```

client should be declared outside the `startup` scope though, eg put the following at the top of the file:

`client = None`

Then assign it a value in `startup`